# Anonymous functions in private static properties

Tags: php, php-7

The simplified version of the code causing issue is:

```
class Test {
    private static $foo = [
        "bar" => "baz",
        "callable" => function() {echo "Derp";}
    ];
};
var_dump(new Test());
```

The above throws:

> **PHP Fatal error:**  Constant expression contains invalid operations in ... on line 5

Is there any clean alternative to this, or will I have to resort to...

```
class Test {
    private static $foo = null;
    public static function initFoo() {
        self::$foo = self::$foo ?? [
            "bar" => "baz",
            "callable" => function() {echo "Derp";}
        ];
    }
}
Test::initFoo();
var_dump(new Test());
```

The above works. Just wondering if there's a better way to do this. It's a shame that callables aren't considered static-able, considering they don't (as far as I can tell) need any evaluation to do - and even then, we have basic operations on static properties now...

Comment: Why not just make 'callable' a static method on the class??

Comment: Because the actual code is a big array of things... I guess the "strictly correct" way to do it would be to have a child class for each type of code... Actually, come to think of it, I might just do that...

Comment: There's not a clean alternative for now, no. Constants can only be nulls, booleans, integers, floats, strings or arrays of those. That might change in a future version, but this is how it is for now. You could use a named function instead maybe and then have `"callable" => "function_name"` (if the function is called `function_name`), but that's not ideal. You could also use a static method (`"callable" => ["Test", "methodName"]`).